# Accessing an object from another thread with Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I have a thread that runs in the background during an asynchronous download. The purpose of the thread is to identify whether or not the download has stopped. My code basically says *"if we haven't downloaded any more bytes in the last 10 seconds, assume the download has failed and do this"*.

When I tried to update a label on my WPF window saying the download had stopped, I was told I couldn't access it from a non-static reference. So I added `MainWindow main = new MainWindow()`, and then added that to the variable to keep from needing the WPF element to be static. But I also needed to use a `Dispatcher` because another thread already owned that object. So my code looked like this:

```
MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
main.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() {
    main.mainTitle.Content = "Unable to connect to the internet";
}));
```

That didn't change anything though, so I changed my approach. I changed the `Dispatcher` to this:

```
MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate() {
    main.mainTitle.Content = "Unable to connect to the internet";
}));
```

However, this appeared to do nothing because on the line that changes the content of the WPF item, I received the error **'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'**

How can I change this object's content from another thread, and why isn't the `Dispatcher` working?

Comment: `new MainWindow()` creates a new MainWindow instance, which is obviously not identical to the one that's already there. Use `(MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow`

Comment: @Clemens You can't do that because that just casts the `Dispatcher` to become type `MainWindow` which you can't really do.

Comment: Read my comment again, with a little more attention.

Comment: Clemens is right, you don't want to `new` a Window here. Find a way to get a reference to the original MainWindow to the thread code, and then use Dispatcher.Invoke().  Application.Current looks fine, if it really is the Main window.

Answer (score 0):

As I see this, you are trying to get some string into the MainWindow. 
The thing is, WPF starts with two Threads. The **UI thread** and the **Render thread**.
The render thread starts rendering the WPF screen and the UI thread is responsible for inputs, handle events...

In your case, you need **permission to access the UI thread** from an other thread, you've created by yourself in code.
My dispatcher looks like this:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
{
     //your code to access property / variable / methods etc
});
```

---

Other way:
Why aren't you using a pattern like MVVM with binding? If you would use binding, you could change the bound property and the value will update automatically in the UI. I'm not sure if the **dispatcher** is a way to access a WPF elements directly from an other thread.